# Automorphism of finite extensions $\mathbb{Q} \subset K$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, automorphism-group

Let $\mathbb{Q} \subset K$ be a finite field extension and $\varphi \in \text{Emb}(K,K)$. I want to show that if $\varphi(x)=y$ then $\varphi (\overline{x}) = \overline{y}$, where $\overline{x}$ denotes complex conjugation. Is the following proof valid?

We know that $\varphi(1)=1$ so $\varphi(n)=n$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence $\varphi(q) = q$, $\forall q \in \mathbb{Q}$. Therefore $\varphi$ restricted to $\mathbb{Q}$ must be the identity.

Now $\varphi(x) = \varphi(x_1 + x_2 i) = \varphi(x_1) +  \varphi(x_2 i) = x_1 + \varphi(x_2 i)$

So $\varphi(\overline{x}) = \varphi(x_1 - x_2 i) = \varphi(x_1) -  \varphi(x_2 i) = x_1 - \varphi(x_2 i)$

Hence we conclude that $\varphi(\overline{x})$ and $\varphi(x)$ are complex conjugates.

Comment: What are $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: $x \in \mathbb{C}$ so $x = x_1 + x_2 i$, where $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: If you want $K\subseteq\mathbb{C}$, you should specify as such. Otherwise this question doesn't make sense. Even then, the claim is not true.

Comment: It is clear that $K$ must be a subset of $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Could you show why the claim is not true via a counter-example or spot any mistake in my proof?

Comment: The mistake is that $\phi(x_2i)$ is in general not proportional to $i$, so your computation does not show that $\varphi(x)$ and $\varphi(\bar{x})$ are complex conjugate.

Comment: But $\overline{\varphi(x)} = \overline {x_1 + \varphi(x_2 i)} = x_1 +  \overline {\varphi(x_2 i)} =  x_1 -  \overline {\varphi(x_2 i)} = \varphi ( \overline{x} ) $

Comment: @john OK so $x_1$ is the real part of $x$. So what then is $\varphi(x_1)$? (I don't see that is meaningful since I see no reason why $x_1$ should be an element of $K$.)

Comment: It is an element of $K$ because it is $(x+\bar{x})/2$, on the other hand it is not in general an element of $\mathbb{Q}$, so it has no reason to be fixed by $\varphi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of pointing out where the argument breaks, let's try a counter-example. We want an extension where the complex conjugation is not in the center of the Galois group (it does not commute with all the automorphisms).

The simplest example is to take a Galois group isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_3$, which has trivial center, and a classical way to do that is to take the splitting field of $X^3-2$, which is $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2},j]$ (where $j$ is a cubic root of unity).

Then there is an automorphism $\varphi$ of $K$ sending $x=\sqrt[3]{2}$ to $y=j\sqrt[3]{2}$, so clearly $\varphi(\bar{x})\neq \bar{y}$.